# Mount a USB unit via ssh to transfer music using Amarok

Tags: mount, android, sshfs, flash-memory, amarok

I want to use Amarok to transfer my audio files to my cellphone (Android). Amarok allows transfer files using only USB drives. Then, I though in mount my cellphone using ssh or sshfs. At the moment, I can mount the content of my mobile in a folder but Amarok only detects USB flash drives. What can I do that Amarok transfers my files through ssh or sshfs? I believe that mount the folder obtained with sshfs as a "USB flash drive" could work, but I am not sure if it's the correct way (and I don't know how to do that too).

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. Why do you want your OS to detect it as a USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do it in usual way.

But you may be able to fake a path as a USB drive.

Try this:

1. Plug in any USB pen drive.
2. Mount it to some point. Say `/media/usb`
3. Mount the other directory on top of it:
   `sudo mount --bind /path/to/other/dir /media/usb`

The software would consider it as USB drive. Though you can't use software
that would do some low level things (like Unetbootin).

Please Note:You will have to `umount /media/usb` twice to unmount the original USB drive.